# "Startup File" on Azure Docker Web App

Tags: azure-container-service

Is the "Startup File" option on the docker web app options for `docker-compose` files? or shell commands? I cannot find any documentation for it...

Basically I'd like my Web App to run a `docker-compose.yml` instead of executing docker run [options] when I push an image to it.

[image: Docker Startup File Option]

Comment: Its for shell (based on my experience where I had it running). Do note your container has a limited time to spin up or Azure just kills it. What defines its alive is responding on port 80 properly.

Answer (score 5):

This is documented now, see below or [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq).

> **What are the expected values for the Startup File section when I
>   configure the runtime stack?**
>
> For Node.js, you specify the PM2 configuration file or your script
>   file. For .NET Core, specify your compiled DLL name as `dotnet <myapp>.dll`. For Ruby, you can specify the Ruby script that you want
>   to initialize your app with.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still a problem but I just noticed it appends whatever you put in there to the default startup command.

```
2019-09-02 05:03:04.493 INFO  - docker run -d -p 55721:80 --name xxxxxx -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxxxx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxxxxxxxx -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 xxxxxx.azurecr.io/xxxxxxx:latest -p 80:4000 -p 443:8000
```

I put the `-p 80:4000 -p 443:8000` into the textbox in the portal config

Comment: By design, the last docker parameter after the image argument is the CMD to execute commands/script (port flags will not work and can only be set before the image parameter)

Answer (score -3):

Azure Web Apps for Containers does not support multi-container apps (with docker-compose) at the time of writing.

Comment: I'm not looking for a multi-container app, but I want to auto-run other commands on startup, which can be achieved with docker-compose. Mainly, starting redis and celery to use with my flask app. [For Example](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/running-background-tasks-with-flask-and-rq/)

Comment: Adding on here... The app I am using is built off this [Image](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker)


I can use supervisor.conf files to launch more processes to be used by my application. I will attempt this with redis and rq

Comment: You can't run a Redis container in Azure Web Apps. The load balancer only allows inbound ports 80 and 443.

Comment: He's not asking to run multi-container apps.