# Azure WebApp for Containers replace docker run

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I'm currently developing an Azure webapp from a container. I want to rewrite the initial docker run that Azure is doing because my container needs some environment variables.

So, I tried different ways but nothing works. For example, if I set my variables inside the 'Startup file' field in the container settings it will append the content in the original docker run, like it is explained here: [StartupFIle in webapp for container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542505/startup-file-on-azure-docker-web-app)

Something like this

```
docker run -d -p 5920:80 --name test -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=test -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=test.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=0 test/myImage:latest -e DB_HOST=test.com:3306 -e DB_DATABASE=test -e DB_USERNAME=test -e DB_PASSWORD=test -e APP_URL=https://test.com
```

Obviously won't work.

I tried to enter into the app using FTPS but I can't find the .env file and cannot connect to the container via ssh because it continues to fail.

So, my question is: How can I upload the initial docker run command that azure container is doing?
I added all my environment variables in the app settings and I can see them in kudu, but I0m missing a step.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using docker compose in the container settings.